# libsvm with different count of Keypoints

Tags: svm, feature-selection, libsvm

I would like to use libsvm for a keypoint detection algorithm. Each keypoint has 36 features, but each sample of an Object has a different count of keypoints...

my input array would look like:

```
Object 1: (K1_F1,...K1_F36,K2_F1,...K2_F36, ... , K12_F1,...K12_F36)

Object 1: (K1_F1,...K1_F36,K2_F1,...K2_F36, ... , K15_F1,...K15_F36)

Object 2: (K1_F1,...K1_F36,K2_F1,...K2_F36, ... , K16_F1,...K16_F36)

Object 2: (K1_F1,...K1_F36,K2_F1,...K2_F36, ... , K9_F1,...K9_F36)
```

Is it even possible to train with different count of keypoints?

Answer (score -1):

In short: **no, it is not possible**. SVM requires **constant shape data representation**. There are two ways for approaching such a problem:

- Create some conversion into constant size representation, one of the most common are clustering methods, bag of words representations and other compression-based approaches.
- Find a suitable kernel function, which for two sets of keypoints returns a valid scalar product value in some space and feed it to the SVM.

Comment: okay! Do you know if I realy need too diffrent Objects for the training? What if I only want to check if the one Object is in my scene or not.